# Cursor for calls index out of bound

Tags: android, null, cursor

I am trying to parse all the log of calls, but when ONLY the first call ends, the cursor is out of bound. It throws 2 exceptions (for date and duration)

Thank you in advance

My code is here:

```
if (c != null && c.getCount()>0) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {!
            type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));
            do {
                try{
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Date is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Calls.DATE)));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Exception: DATE IS NULL!!");
                }
            //String timestamp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Calls.DATE));
                //Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"timestamp is: "+timestamp);
                try{
                    long duration= c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Exception:  DURATION IS NULL!!");
                }
                //callDuration.put(timestamp, duration);
            }
            while (!c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a do -  while loop, I think the condition needs to be true for the loop to continue.

So your code should say

do  {
       this 
    }
     while (c.moveToNext());

When the condition becomes false, the loop will exit.

The explanation is here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html